# Retrieve all folder in a directories and change all folders' name that are in it

Tags: php, directory

I want to retrieve all folders in a directory folder and change all the subfolder that in it. For example,
in root folder Root, I want to change all subfolders A, B, C, D, .. to 1,2,34,... May I know how can I do it with php? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  To get you on the right track, you'll need to look at `scandir`, `is_dir` and `rename` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$count = 0;
foreach(new DirectoryIterator('Root') as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDir() && !$fileInfo->isDot()) {
        $count++;
        rename($fileInfo->getPathName(), $fileInfo->getPath() . "/$count");
    }
}
```

---

Links:

- [`DirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)
- [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)
- [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) (if you with to do the same for sub-directories)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$basedir = "/tmp"; //or whatever your "to change" home directory is

$contents = scandir($basedir);
$count = 1;

foreach ($contents as $check) {
    if (is_dir($basedir . "/" . $check) && $check != "." && $check != "..") {
        rename($basedir . "/" . $check, $basedir . "/" . $count);
        $count++;
    }
}

?>
```

Of course, you will need to have proper CHMOD depending on where you run the script from.